# Creating files based on already existing files with a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a directory that contains some nonsensically named files, for example:

```
apple_2020-01-01.txt
apple_2020-01-02.txt
orange_2020-01-01.txt
pear_2020-01-02.txt
pear_2020-01-03.txt
pear_2020-01-04.txt
```

I want to use a bash script to create some new files based on the timestamps on the files, one file for each unique timestamp.

There are some assumptions I can make:

1) the file names will always follow the format of fruit_*.txt

2) the files will either be named apple, orange, or pear

3) the timestamp will always be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Based on the above example files, I'd expect the following files to be created by the script:

```
NewFile_2020-01-01.txt
NewFile_2020-01-02.txt
NewFile_2020-01-03.txt
NewFile_2020-01-04.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want in say `NewFile_2020-01-01.txt` - the contents of {apple,orange}_2020-01-01.txt or are you just after the filenames?

Comment: @icarus Just the file name. The contents would be empty, so creating them with a `touch` command would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for file in {apple,pear,orange}_*.txt; do
    touch "NewFile_${file##*_}";
done
```

For each file, we remove the leading part until the underscore character, so only the timestamp and extension is left, and then prepend `NewFile_` to the result.

`touch` will not complain if it tries to create a file that already exist.

This solution will also work if there are blank spaces after underscore.

Comment: Will this solution also work if there are extra characters before the first underscore, but before the timestamp? i.e. if the files were called `apple_2020-01-01.txt`, `an_orange_2020-01-01.txt`, and `lots_of_pears_2020-01-01.txt`, would the `touch` command still properly name the new files?

Comment: It will work under the question assumptions. Only files beginning with `apple_`, `orange_` or `pear_` **and** ending with `.txt` are considered by the script, as determined by the regex `{apple,pear,orange}_*.txt`. Files named otherwise are simply ignored. So if you add `an_orange_1212-12-12.txt` to the list in your question, you won't get `NewFile_1212-12-12.txt`, although one could easily adapt the script to take variations into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%s\n' {apple,orange,pear}_*.txt | 
     sed 's/apple\|orange\|pear/NewFile' |
     sort -u |
     xargs touch
```

Use shell glob to get the filenames (this will fail if there are not any, and there are tens of thousands it could be a problem), used sed to change the names, then use sort -u to remove duplicates.

Finally feed them to xargs touch to create the files as per the OP's clarification comment.

Answer (score 0):

`ls *.txt | cut -f2- -d_ | sort -u | xargs -IX touch NewFile_X`

- `cut` gives the 2nd "field" with a delimiter of `_`
- `sort` sorts and removes dupes (`u`nique)
- `xargs` runs the command `touch` and replaces `X` with what came in from the others

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: For quick and dirty command line, using `ls` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: We don't know if this is for a quick and dirty command line task or not. Maybe this is for some small part of a production system where the real files names contain newlines. Rather than guessing and not mentioning the issues, IMHO it's best if the OP has a heads up about the issues around parsing ls if that's the proposed solution to their problem.